# Creating classes matrix without for loops

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to create a classes matrix in MATLAB preferably without using for loops.  So I have `A`:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4;
      2 5 4 1;
      7 2 3 4];
```

Now I want to create a classes matrix so I want to look for the max value of each column and whatever that position is will become a "1".  So using `A`, I want `B` to look like this:

```
B = [ 0 0 0 1;
      0 1 0 0;
      1 0 0 0];
```

I've been trying to use the following code to create the `B` matrix and then search for the max value in each column using the following code:

```
 [rows_A columns_A] = size(A);
 B = zeros(rows_A, columns_A);
 max(A, [], 2);
```

Then I'm trying to use `ind2sub` to get the position within `A` so I can put a "1" in the `B` matrix.  This approach isn't working out.  The matrix `A` can be of any dimensions.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to flag the column with the largest value for each row as follows:

```
[~,indMaxCol] = max(A,[],2);
B = zeros(size(A));
B(sub2ind(size(B),1:size(B,1),indMaxCol.')) = 1  %' flag largest column, each row
B =
     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0
```

Another solution, which does not require `sub2ind` is to create a [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix:

```
Bs = sparse(1:size(B,1),indMaxCol,1)
Bs =
   (3,1)        1
   (2,2)        1
   (1,4)        1
```

This can be converted to a [full matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) with `full(Bs)`.

Answer (score 1):

One-line solution with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) (compute the maximum for each row and then compare for equality):

```
bsxfun(@eq, A, max(A,[],2))
```

This differs from @chappjc's solution in one aspect: if the maximum is achieved more than once in some row, this gives *all* columns where the maximum is attained. For example:

```
>> A = [ 4     2     3     4
         2     5     4     1
         7     2     3     4 ];

>> bsxfun(@eq, A, max(A,[],2))

ans =

     1     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: ... And if you want _only the first_ maximum in each row, you can use the following (still one line; admittedly not very clear but hey):
`diff([zeros(size(A,1),1) logical(cumsum(bsxfun(@eq, A, max(A,[],2)),2))],[],2)`